# How to define listTree so that it returns a list containing all the elements in order?

Tags: haskell, tree, fold

```
listTree :: Tree a -> [a]
listTree = foldTree f z
    where
    f x y z  = x + y + z
    z = []
```

This is what I have so far, but my f is wrong because the expected type is `Tree a -> [a]` but the actual is `Tree [a] -> [a]`

```
data Tree a
   = Tip
   | Bin (Tree a) a (Tree a)
   deriving (Show, Eq)

foldTree :: (b -> a -> b -> b) -> b -> Tree a -> b
foldTree f z Tip         = z
foldTree f z (Bin l x r) = f (foldTree f z l) x (foldTree f z r)
```

This is fold and data type for tree.

Need help with defining `f`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, combining lists uses `++` in haskell. `+` is only used for adding numbers. Second, the variable `y` is of type `a`, not `[a]`, so you cannot use `++` on it directly.

```
listTree :: Tree a -> [a]
listTree = foldTree f z
    where
    f x y z = x ++ [y] ++ z
    z = []
```